# Unity Container Interface Resolve Through Abstract Class

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have the following code.

```
public interface ISomeInterface
    {
        bool DoSomething();
    }
public abstract class A:ISomeInterface
{
    public abstract string DoSomething();
}

public class B : A
{

    public override string DoSomething()
    {
        return "Class B method";
    }
}

public class C : A
{

    public override string DoSomething()
    {
        return "Class C method";
    }
}
```

I am trying to resolve it like below

```
<register type="ISomeInterface,SomeAssembly" mapTo="B,SomeAssembly" name="B" />
<register type="ISomeInterface,SomeAssembly" mapTo="C,SomeAssembly" name="C" />
```

but I am getting config error and with abstract class mapping it works fine.

What am I missing?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Looks like you are missing like below...

Comment: Can you provide the error you are getting?

Comment: does that even compile? `DoSomething` should return `bool`.